# Updating Content of app without resubmitting to the App Store? For IOS and objective c code

Tags: ios, updating

I am new here and made this account to ask this question. I would like to know how you can update the content of your app without resubmitting the whole app to the AppStore. The content doesn't change the app functionality, just the content displayed like new articles and news events. It would be a long process to have to keep resubmitting. If a news event happened recently, I would want the app to be on point and show that event quickly. How could I update it to all my users? Is there a way to do it over wifi? I would appreciate any help. I am fairly new to this as well, so please excuse me.

Comment: You can't update the app itself like this. Apps that require real time data updates usually fetch it from a server somewhere on the internet when the app starts (etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. When you submit the app, Apple reviews it and if it passes review Apple digitally signs it. It won't run on any iOS device without Apple's signature. Any change you make, no matter how insignificant, will break the signature.

To get fast-breaking news out to your customers, don't put the news in the app. Put it on a server you control, and have the app fetch it from there. Apple understands this process; in fact, they expect you to have a server somewhere.

If you want to get the news out very quickly, push it to your users. The mechanism is that your server pushes a notification to Apple, and Apple forwards the notification to all your users (unless they've disabled notifications from your app, which is certainly their prerogative).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't mean to change the app itself, just update articles and add more stories. A server seems like the way to go. I appreciate all the help I have gotten. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends, if you are talking about contents you can easily update them by downloading from a server, when the app is launched or resumed from background.
If you are talking about runtime execution you can create a configuration file that you can download from a remote URL, that can contain boolean, strings, number to define a sort of behavior or path during app execution.

Comment: How would someone achieve something like this? Where would you store this configuration file?

Comment: The configuration file is of course a remote resource. The best is to have one config file in app resources and one remote. When the app sees that the remote file is updates from the embedded it updates it.